# 8.1 to 10 setup : Something happened > Setup has failed to validate the product key

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation, windows-10-upgrade, product-key

Just like millions of other users, I'm attempting to upgrade to windows 10. I have a Dell laptop running 8.1, which had windows reinstalled once. That was because I swapped the HDD out for a SSD and I used a usb stick provided by dell to do the reinstallation. On a second laptop (identical make, model and SSD swap) I did the exact same procedure in everything and it's working like a charm...this one however keeps failing with the error described in the title (well....at least I think it translates to that, as I run the Dutch version). So far I tried a lot of things I found on the internet and nothing works so far.

Any help is greatly appreciated, as I am going to need the Edge browser in the near future.

[image: Picture of the error]

Comment: You performed a clean install it upgrade?

Comment: No I did not perform a clean install...I need to upgrade it from within 8.1 first to get a valid windows 10 key. And it's not even letting me install. The process goes like this: Clicking setup > Choose not to download the updates now > And it will fail 30 seconds later.

Comment: Yes I know; it is the reason I asked

Comment: ISO or get windows method?

Comment: I used the media creation tool with the upgrade this pc option. (no iso)

Comment: Try downloading the updates

Comment: same result if I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying again for many times I figured it might be a software conflict of sorts, I created a new user account and tried it from there and it worked like a charm! I hope this helps others !

Answer (score 1):

The picture roughly translates to

**something happened**

failed to validate product key

Media creation tool provides option to convert to ISO and install it using USB 
and DVDs which allows us to edit the supporting files.
You can go to sources folder and find ei.cfg configuration file

[image]

Now open ei.cfg and modify it as given below

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reset your PC under Advanced Startup

- From the start menu, choose the power icon
  (note: any power icon will do. If you can't access one, follow another way from here https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2294-boot-advanced-startup-options-windows-10-a.html)
- Hold down shift and choose to restart
- Hold shift until a blue screen pops up with icons. Select Troubleshoot
- Choose Reset this PC and choose to save your files; I did and the reset worked just fine
- Follow prompts and your computer should work again!